# Total differential of composite function

Tags: multivariable-calculus

Let function $f(x,y)$ is defined at neighborhood of $(1,1)$ and has a continous partial derivations here. Let $g(x,y) = f(f(x,y), f(y,x))$ and we know, that $f(1,1) = 1$, $\partial _x f(1,1) = 1$ and $\partial _y f(1,1) = 2$.

How to compute a total differential of $g$ in $(1,1)$?

Comment: See [http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Total_derivative](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Total_derivative)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $g(x,y)=f(f(x,y),f(x,y))$.  Then,

$$\begin{align}
dg(x,y)&=f_1(f(x,y),f(x,y))\,df+f_2(f(x,y),f(x,y))\,df\\\\
&=[f_1(f(x,y),f(x,y))+f_2(f(x,y),f(x,y))]\,df\\\\
&=[f_1(f(x,y),f(x,y))+f_2(f(x,y),f(x,y))]\,\left(f_1(x,y)dx+f_2(x,y)dy\right)
\end{align}$$

At $(1,1)$, we know that $f(1,1)=1$, $f_1(1,1)=1$, and $f_2(1,1)=2$.  Thus,

> $$dg(1,1)=3dx+6dy$$